# how to select all columns from a list in a polars dataframe

Tags: python, select, python-polars

I have a dataframe

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "nrs": [1, 2, 3, None, 5],
        "names": ["foo", "ham", "spam", "egg", None],
        "random": np.random.rand(5),
        "groups": ["A", "A", "B", "C", "B"],
    }
)
```

I want to select only the columns in `list`:

```
mylist = ['nrs', 'random']
```

This seems to work:

```
import polars.selectors as cs
df.select(cs.by_name(mylist)))
```

Is this the idiomatic way to do it? Or are there better ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually simpler than that:

```py
df.select(['nrs', 'random'])

┌──────┬──────────┐
│ nrs  ┆ random   │
│ ---  ┆ ---      │
│ i64  ┆ f64      │
╞══════╪══════════╡
│ 1    ┆ 0.662732 │
│ 2    ┆ 0.437345 │
│ 3    ┆ 0.43857  │
│ null ┆ 0.701177 │
│ 5    ┆ 0.390494 │
└──────┴──────────┘
```

[selectors](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/selectors.html) are in general for more complicated selections - like all string columns, column starting with certain phrase and so on.

As written in [`select()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.select.html) documentation you can either path list of columns or expression there.

so any of these work - `.select('nrs', 'random')`, `.select(pl.col('nrs', 'random'))`, `.select(pl.col('nrs'), pl.col('random'))`.

Comment: You're right, it was in the documentation. I'm not sure how I missed it - I've been reading `polars` docs for the best part of the day, and I must have missed this step.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the list of column names to the `select` method.

```
df.select(['nrs', 'random'])
```

Answer (score 0):

[`pl.col()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/col.html) is the "idiomatic" way.

```py
df.select(pl.col(mylist))
```

```py
# shape: (5, 2)
# ┌──────┬──────────┐
# │ nrs  ┆ random   │
# │ ---  ┆ ---      │
# │ i64  ┆ f64      │
# ╞══════╪══════════╡
# │ 1    ┆ 0.499871 │
# │ 2    ┆ 0.652411 │
# │ 3    ┆ 0.068664 │
# │ null ┆ 0.496422 │
# │ 5    ┆ 0.227972 │
# └──────┴──────────┘
```

Some examples of what it supports:

- `pl.col("a", "b")` by name (positional args)
- `pl.col(["a", "b"])` by name (list)
- `pl.col("^regex_pattern$")` by regex ("matches")
- `pl.col(pl.String)` by dtype

The Selectors API was added later to offer more powerful functionality.

Due to some of the overlapping behaviour, it looks like the selectors api functionality will be merged into the main namespace:

- https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/13757